# "O meno" vs "o no"

Tags: difference, phrase-choice

I have read the following definition of a word:

> "porzione di spazio delimitata materialmente o meno"

Google Translate told me that "o meno" means "or not". Could I say "o no" instead? If so, is there any difference between both?

Comment: Avoid “o meno”. In this case use “o no”, in other cases, nothing. For instance, something like “decidiamo se andare alla spiaggia o meno” is frequently heard, but the “o meno” or the “o no” is redundant and should be omitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: "o no" is not only possible, but also more correct.
"O meno" is widely used but not recommandable in phrases like this one (can something be delimited "less materially"?).

http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/o-no-o-non-o-meno_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/

Comment: Sometimes "o no" sounds a bit strange; you can use also "oppure no"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Isn't "o" = "oppure" ? "strange" is subjective. Maybe you meant "idiomatically unusual"?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista yes, "oppure" is a "stronger" version of "o"; maybe I should have written "sometimes _o no_ sounds not good" ;) I agree that it is subjective